# While-loop inside else-statement not printing all answers

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop, search-engine

I got this code, which is linked to a search field on my index page:

```
<?php
   ini_set('display_errors', 2);
   $search = $_GET ['q'];
   $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","release");
   $query    = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM game WHERE game_name LIKE '%". $search ."%'");
   $foundnum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query); 
   $count = count($foundnum['game_name']);


   if ($foundnum == 0) {
      echo "No results found. Either this game doesn't exist, or we have yet to add it. Please contact us!";
      }
         else {
           while($foundnum= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
           {
              echo "$count result(s) found!<p>";
              echo"<pre/>";print_r($foundnum['game_name']);
              echo"<pre/>";print_r($foundnum['game_release']);
           }
      }
?>
```

Everything's working fine without the `while`-loop, but because some search terms ('car' for example), should print both Project CARS and Rise of Incarnates, I need a `while`-loop.

I tried putting the `while`-loop before the `if`-statement as well, but that doesnt work either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: searching for `car` certainly never will find `CAR` with a case sensitive search.

Comment: Also note that you use the database connector without the benefit it offers: to protect you from sql injections. You want to read about "prepared statements".

Comment: Oh, and the answer why that won't show all results: `mysqli_fetch_assoc` fetches a row in the result set. You fetch the first row in line 6, afterwards it is gone, since you immediately fetch the next row in line 14. That also means that probably line 7 does not make any sense (though you don't use `$count` anyway...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some correction in your code.. please re-veirfy using below code

I have tried the code using my db tables and it is showing correct values...

```
    <?php
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    $search = $_GET['q'];
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "release");
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM game WHERE game_name LIKE '%" . $search . "%'");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query); // right way to find row count

    if ($count == 0)
    {
        echo "No results found. Either this game doesn't exist, or we have yet to add it. Please contact us!";
    }
    else
    {
        while ($foundnum = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            echo "$count result(s) found!<p>";
            echo"<pre>";
            print_r($foundnum['game_name']);
            echo"</pre><pre>";
            print_r($foundnum['game_code']);
            echo"</pre>";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

if you want to search `insensitively` (i.e ignoring capital and small letters) than do let me know.. I will update the code

Comment: The query is currently showing both Project CARS and Rise of Incarnates when I'm searching for 'car', so is that still necessary then?

Comment: @MichaelCox yes.. we are using `%` both the side of the search keyword.. so it will search all the words containing `car`... :P